# Combining two monochrome bitmaps to one colorful

Tags: .net, image-processing, bitmap

I have a button, which may be in two states: pressed and unpressed. Each state is represented by monochrome (black & white) bitmap, which can be edited in my simple editor. What I want is to to display one colorful bitmap which combines somehow those two bitmaps so that user can see all information on the one picture. How this can be achieved?

Comment: How exactly do you propose to combine two monochrome bitmaps and produce a **color** bitmap?

Comment: That is the subject of question how. I want to be able to look at the one picture and get the idea of how both images looks comparing to each other.

Comment: You can't get a color picture from two monochrome pictures. You also can't get water from wine. At least not without some magic ingredients.

Comment: Of course I can. For example, I can set pixel to black if both images have black pixel there, white - if both pixels white. Gray - if first picture have black pixel and second white, yellow - in opposite situation. Hm... it seems that I answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can put them as 2 channels of a color image (e.g. using `cvMerge()`)
2. You can add them together (properly scaled)
3. You can XOR them.
4. Try playing with Photoshop's layer options (Multiply, screen, transparencies etc.)